# Rackspace ad has broken link

Tags: bug, advertising

The ad with image

```
http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes///Site-16990/Type-0/305e03c3-56df-4f1d-8b26-9b5a16f45102.jpg
```

is linking to

```
http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6MjA4MTIsImF0IjoxNywiY20iOjU3NzEwLCJjaCI6MTE3OCwiY3IiOjExNjcwNywiZGkiOiJhZDRkZDM3MDQwOGM0NDk4YjkxYTk4Zjg4MzZkYWUxMSIsImRtIjoxLCJmYyI6MjE4MDQ0LCJmbCI6MTA3MDc0LCJrdyI6Imh0bWwsY3NzLHVuaWNvZGUsZm9udC1mYWNlLHdlYmZvbnRzLHgtdXNlci1yZWdpc3RlcmVkLHgtMTUwMHBsdXMtcmVwIiwibWsiOiJodG1sIiwibnciOjIyLCJwYyI6NS40MiwicHIiOjc2NSwicnQiOjIsInJmIjoiaHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3Bvc3RzLzIxMzU5ODE4L2VkaXQiLCJzdCI6ODI3Nywiem4iOjQ1LCJ0cyI6MTM5MDcyNDU3MTQ5MSwidXIiOm51bGx9&s=ZEl9c2ktRTBPyeGueyZRtitin3Ehttps%3a//bs.serving%2dsys.com/BurstingPipe/BannerRedirect.bs?cn=brd%26FlightID=6577022%26Page=%26sessionid=3091661577133372732%26PluID=0%26EyeblasterID=18231060%26Pos=4166577981476%26ord=107161476
```

which returns `Bad Request` (HTTP 400).

Comment: That's not something the community here can do much about. Try reporting this to Adzerk instead, perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don’t know how the ads work here. 4xx are client errors, the error should be in the URL (maybe too long?), not in the server. If the URL is supplied by Adzerk, I agree with you. Do you know how to contact them? Their site has contact form just for the sales department (if I did not miss any other). I prefer email. Snail mail is slow and costly, long URLs are hard to dictate over phone (which is also costly).

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to contact them. Stack Exchange sites merely use javascript supplied by Adzerk to produce the advertisement HTML markup, so if a advertisement produces a URL that results in an exception, Stack Exchange would simply forward the problem to them anyway.

Comment: Adzerk has a contact form at http://adzerk.com/contact that specifically mentions feedback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I’ll write them and post their reply here if any comes.

Comment: We're looking into the issue as well. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @stevvve Should I leave it to you then? I did not find time to contact Adzerk today.

Comment: @Palec Yep! This is very much my responsibility. :-) Having trouble reproducing the error, at the moment, though. Will do some more investigating tomorrow.

Comment: @stevvve Did you find anything? I am using Firefox 17.0.11esr if that helps. But I think this error is not a matter of user agent. Can I help anyhow with reproducing?

Comment: Today I met another Rackspace ad and the link worked OK. It began with (ellipsis at the end) `https://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/BannerRedirect.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=6577022&Page=&sessionid=3758842781871422631&PluID=0&EyeblasterID=18231059&Pos=4167026322104&ord=145062104&sct=1&ncu=$$http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=eyJhdiI6MjA4MTIsImF0IjoxNywiY20iOjU3NzEwLCJjaCI6MTE3OCwiY3IiOjExNjcwNywiZGkiOiI0ODk2MGM2ZjAyN2U0YWQ1ODg4ODQ0NmQyMDg2YzdlNSIsImRtIjoxLCJmYyI6MjE4MDQ0LCJmbCI6MTA3MDc0LCJrdyI6ImphdmFzY3JpcHQsaHRtbCxpZnJhbWUseC11c2VyLXJlZ2lzdGVyZWQseC0xNTAwcGx1cy1yZXAiLCJtayI6Imh0bWwsamF2YXNjcmlwdCIsIm5…`

Comment: Okay. Are you still seeing issues or has the successful ad replaced the unsuccessful one? I still can't seem to reproduce in Chrome, IE or Firefox.

Comment: @stevvve Not sure if the problem disappeared, because I don’t visit links from ads so often. But I think that the chances are it is over. It could be non-deterministic too, but I think we can neglect that possibility for now. If I come across the same problem again, I’ll report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error no longer observed. Any future instances should be reported in a new Meta post.

Thank you for keeping an eye out!